# GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT when attaching a cube map texture to a frame buffer object (FBO)

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

In order to support shadow mapping for point lights, I need to render my depth values to the 6 sides of a cubemap.

My init function looks like this:

```
public void init(int width, int height) {
    fboId = GL30.glGenFramebuffers();

    GL11.glEnable(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    cubeMap = GL11.glGenTextures();

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubeMap);

    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
            GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
            GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GL11.GL_CLAMP);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GL11.GL_CLAMP);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL12.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R,
            GL11.GL_CLAMP);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0,
                GL14.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, width, height, 0,
                GL11.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL11.GL_FLOAT, (FloatBuffer) null);

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
}
```

This is the function I use to bind a side of the cube map to my FBO:

```
public void bindForWriting(int target) {
    // target is GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X etc.

    GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
    GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,
            GL30.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, target, cubeMap, 0);

    // Disable writes to the color buffer.
    GL11.glDrawBuffer(GL11.GL_NONE);

    int fboStat = GL30.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL30.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER);

    if (fboStat != GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        // fboStat is always == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT
    }

    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

Unfortunately, the FBO is incomplete and I can't figure out why. The [Khronos](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml) site says: "Not all framebuffer attachment points are framebuffer
attachment complete. This means that at least one
                        attachment point with a renderbuffer or texture 
                        attached has its attached object no longer in existence
                        or has an attached image with a width or height of 
                        zero, or the color attachment point has a 
                        non-color-renderable image attached, or the
                        depth attachment point has a non-depth-renderable
                        image attached, or the stencil attachment point has a
                        non-stencil-renderable image attached.
                        Color-renderable formats include GL_RGBA4,
                        GL_RGB5_A1, and
                        GL_RGB565.
                        GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 is the only
                        depth-renderable format. 
                        GL_STENCIL_INDEX8 is the only
                        stencil-renderable format."

I did not destroy the cube map and width/height are > 0. I can't see why GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 is the only depth-renderable format, because the FBO I am using for spot light shadow mapping works fine with GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32. If I change it to GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, the same error still happens.

Any advice?

Comment: So what does `bindForWriting` get called with?

Comment: bindForWriting gets called with the side of the cube to write on: GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z

Comment: I used glGetError to see which line generates errors. It seems like `GL11.glTexImage2D(GL13.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0,
                GL14.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, width, height, 0,
                GL11.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL11.GL_FLOAT, (FloatBuffer) null);`
produces
`GL_INVALID_VALUE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem:

GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if target is one of the six cube map 2D image targets and **the width and height parameters are not equal**.
[Source](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml).